# Prolog if sentence conditions

Tags: prolog

So basically I am trying to check in the middle of a `rule` if certain conditions are met but the condition depends on another variable. 
In my case if the `Num1` is 10, then the `Num2` can't be 1 - if it is 1 then fail and if the `Num1` is 20, then `Num2` can't be 2.

This is something I came up with

```
do_function(Num1, Num2):-
   write('first'),
   ((Num1 = 10, Num2 \= 1); (Num1 = 20, Num2 \= 2)),
   write('last').
```

The `query` that it works with:

```
 ?- do_function(20, 1).
 firstlast
 true.
```

But with this `query` I get:

```
?- do_function(10, 2).
firstlast
true ;
false.
```

In this case it writes `firstlast` for some reason, but in my actual code it does the first part and then crashes, because of the `false` it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can ensure that the checking predicate is only called with bound arguments, then use the if-then-else control construct. E.g.

```
do_function(Num1, Num2) :-
    (   Num1 =:= 10 ->
        Num2 =\= 1
    ;   Num1 =:= 20 ->
        Num2 =\= 2
    ;   true
    ).
```

Also take a look to the `library(clpfd)`. Depending on the problem that you're trying to solve, using constraints may be a better alternative.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for, but can you tell me the difference between `=`, `=:=` and `\=`, `=\=`. Or point me to the source.

Comment: The `=:=/2` and `=\=/2` predicates are arithmetic comparison predicates. The `=/2` and `\=/2` predicates are term unification predicates. See the documentation of the Prolog system you're using for details.

Answer (score 1):

Simply translating your rule (and assuming you meant `N1` is 20):

> In my case if the `Num1` is 10, then the `Num2` can't be 1 - if it is 1 then fail and if the `Num2` is 20, then `Num2` can't be 2.

to Prolog code:

```
do_function(N1, N2) :- N1 is 10, N2 \= 1.
do_function(N1, N2) :- N1 is 20, N2 \= 2.
```

or:

```
do_function(10, N2) :- N2 \= 1.
do_function(20, N2) :- N2 \= 2.
```

Comment: `=\=/2` (arithmetic expression comparison) would be preferable here to `\=/2` (term unification). But your solution doesn't cover the case where `N1` is neither `10` nor `20`.

Comment: The question is not about generic solution.